How to Modify and Return Telemetry Data from a Device Using ThingsBoard?
I am using ThingsBoard to manage IoT devices and need to dynamically modify telemetry data received from a device before sending it back to ThingsBoard. Specifically, I need to subtract or add a certain value to a telemetry parameter and then send this value back to the device. I also need to customize an HTML widget, as I cannot use Control Widgets like the RPC Button, Knob Control, or Switch Control to send commands to my devices.

How can I create a custom widget that adds an action to it? If it is not possible
How can I use a Rule Chain, where the problem is that I need to activate the rule chain from the dashboard, for example, I need a button on the dashboard, when I click this button the rule chain should be activated and do some subtraction from the current value and send the value back?

Thank you!
